# Codeigniter session destroy on browser close doesn't work

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-2

I'm using Codeigniter 2.2.0, trying to set my session in order to destroy session when a browser is closed. In my `application/config/config.php`, I have set

```
 $config['sess_use_database']   = TRUE;
 $config['sess_expire_on_close']    = TRUE;
```

but it doesn't work. The session that stored in database is not destroy. I try to do this:

```
$this->session->set_userdata(array('user'=>'user1','login'=>TRUE));
```

and the session is stored in database with serialize user_data. And then I close the browser, and open the browser again, and run the same code above. Because the first session is not deleted from table, now I got 2 record in the session table with the same value in user_data column, but different session_id value. All I want is the first session must be destroyed and also deleted from database.

How can I fix this problem? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try an ajax request for expiring session:

```
var sessionExpire = function(e){
        //here ajax request to expire session
  };
window.unload = sessionExpire;
```

Comment: Last time I tried to add javascript to check when window is close using `unload` function, but looks like it now working as well, because when the page is reload, the `unload` function will run the script. On my page, I use `setInterval()` function to reload the page every 5 seconds. So If I use `unload` function, I can only access my page 5 seconds.